# Linux find all mounted CDROMs from C code

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I need to write function in C language on Linux which accesses all mounted CDROMs and performs some action.
I can do it on BSD using

```
count = getmntinfo(&buf, 0);
```

And looping on all devices and checking

```
buf[i].f_type == 17
```

Is any way to do the same on Linux?

Comment: Just to be clear: what's your definition of a CD-ROM? Does a DVD-ROM or BD-ROM count? What about a mounted ISO image of any of the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is probably to parse /proc/mounts.  It looks identical to /etc/mtab, but this is not actually an on disk file, it's a kernel interface, and you should use low level file descriptor functions with it -- ie, read(), not fread(), fscanf(), etc.  Virtually all linux systems that mount a cdrom will also have a proc available, and much of it (inluding mounts) does not require privileges to read.

There is also libudev, but I *think* that solution will be a lot more convoluted:

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/libudev/

Again, virtually all linux systems that mount a cd will also use udev, although I think this is a little less true that it would be for proc.

/sys/dev contains more in-depth information about each mounted device that might enable you to make a determination.  libudev uses those paths.

Really, to respect the user, I think you should try and stick with conventional symlinks like /dev/dvdrw, etc, and not try so much to find things in unconventional places.  That's what those links are for.  It also makes your job much much easier.

Comment: And how can I check if device is CDROM?

Comment: Check if the filesystem is `udf` or `iso9660`? That's the only thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: Also, /dev names do follow a system: http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/linux/docs/device-list/devices-2.6+.txt, but this will not be unequivocal either.  Looks like udev does have a "devtype" string, you may want to investigate that in conjunction with /proc/mounts (ie, parse /proc/mounts and try all reasonable cantidates).  libudev makes use of the /sys/dev paths, see my edit above.

Comment: /dev/ files are not ordinary files but pointers into the kernel to activate some device specific code. These pointers can exist even if the related devices are not present on the hardware. So it would not be a good idea to find /dev/sr0 on computers that do not have the optical drive.

Comment: *"These pointers can exist even if the related devices are not present"* No, there are no such dummy nodes that represent potentially real but missing hardware.  They are created (and removed) dynamically by the kernel when the hardware is attached to the system.  Ie., if you have an sr0 you have an optical drive.  If you remove it, sr0 will disappear.